# How can I print out information about a Wireless Access Point in range?

Tags: networking, wifi

How can I print out information about a Wireless Access Point in range? Can I for example get the MAC address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
iwlist <interface> scan
```

For example:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Also, using pipes and `egrep`, and practicing a little with `iwlist scan`, you can extract the info you want:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan | egrep 'Address:|ESSID:'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Linux then you can usually just do

```
ifconfig
```

or

```
iwconfig
```

to get info on your NIC.  To scan you usually do

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

to get info on the wireless access points in range.  In this case your wireless interface has already been identified using `ifconfig` (or `iwconfig`) as `wlan0`.